# add text overlay the animation with animate package

Tags: beamer, animate

I want to do a tutorial with  Beamer and the animate package.

I have an animation containing several hundred .png images, I would like to add text overlay to comment on the different sequences of the tutorial.

The text must appear for example from image id-50 to image id-75.

I did some testing, with timeline, but I did not have the expected result.

Can you tell me the procedure?

=============================

Comment: I would try the `overpic` environment (defined by the pkg of the same name) inside the `\multiframe` loop of `animate` in order to place labels on the included images. You can put multiple `\multiframe` loops inside the `animateinline` environment to annotate sections of the animation differently. Dont forget to place a `\newframe` between subsequent `\multiframes`.

Comment: Can you add a MWE and show where you want the text to go?

Comment: @rpapa We'd like to keep answers separate from questions, so you should write a separate answer instead of editing your answer into the question. Self-answers are perfectly admissible, and a well-written answer may earn you additional reputation.

Comment: @rpapa : If you want an automatic pause between two sections, you can use `\newframe*`.  Also, buttons can be inserted to jump to the start of individual sections. (Making use of `animate`'s JavaScript interface.)

Answer (score 2):

I reply myself, from the remark of AlexG

I inserted the images in a tikz figure and added the text in a node that I superimposed to the node containing the image

```
\begin{frame}{Animated frame + text}


\begin{animateinline}[controls, autoplay, poster=first]{8}  
\multiframe{20}{n=0+1}{
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node(img){\includegraphics[,width=0.8\linewidth]{./simu/image-\n}};
    \node[above=1em of img.south,fill=yellow,opacity=0.5,text width=12em,align=center]{Some text};
  \end{tikzpicture}    
}
\newframe
\multiframe{20}{n=20+1}{
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node(img){\includegraphics[,width=0.8\linewidth]{./simu/image-\n}};
    \node[above=1em of img.south,fill=green,opacity=0.5,text width=12em,align=center]{Another text};
  \end{tikzpicture}    
}
\newframe
\multiframe{20}{n=40+1}{
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node(img){\includegraphics[,width=0.8\linewidth]{./simu/image-\n}};
    \node[above=1em of img.south,fill=blue,opacity=0.5,text width=12em,align=center]{%
    third text
};
  \end{tikzpicture}    
}

\end{animateinline}


\end{frame}
```